# How can AES iv be used correctly

Tags: encryption, aes

I have done some searching and found that IV must be unique. And that is vital.

However could it be safe to that can it be unique per user?

So many files, messages are encrypted with 1 IV for only 1 user?

Comment: What’s keeping you from having unique iv for each cipher? It’s not secret, you can send it along with the cipher, eg. separated by a dot to tell where one ends and another starts.

Comment: IVs are free, why treat them like precious commodity?

Comment: IVs must be unique per encryption key, not per user. A given IV+Key pair should never be reused for multiple messages (*must* never be reused for certain modes). There are more than 10¹⁹ possible IVs. You're not going to run out.